# How do I grab rows surrounding a flagged value?

Tags: sql, sas

I'm starting with a table like this:

```
code     new_code_flag
abc123   0
xyz456   0
wer098   1
jio234   0
bcx190   0
eiw157   0
nzi123   0
epj676   0
ere654   0
yru493   1
ale674   0
```

I want to grab the 2 records before and 2 records after each value where "new_code_flag"=1.  I want my output to look like this:

```
code     new_code_flag
abc123   0
xyz456   0
wer098   1
jio234   0
bcx190   0
epj676   0
ere654   0
yru493   1
ale674   0
```

Any help on how to do this in SQL or SAS?

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Hence, in SQL you need to have a column that specifies the ordering.  Assuming you do, you can do something like:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by ?) as seqnum
      from tbl t
     )
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.new_code_flag = 1 and
                    t.seqnum between t2.seqnum - 2 and t2.seqnum + 2
             );
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I've been going crazy trying to figure this out (obviously a newbie over here) & this worked perfectly the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two lag and two lead copies of the flag variable and then test if any of the 5 variables are 1 (true).

```
data have;
  input code $ flag ;
cards;
abc123   0
xyz456   0
wer098   1
jio234   0
bcx190   0
eiw157   0
nzi123   0
epj676   0
ere654   0
yru493   1
ale674   0
;

data want ;
  set have ;
  set have(keep=flag rename=(flag=lead1_flag) firstobs=2) have(drop=_all_ obs=1);
  set have(keep=flag rename=(flag=lead2_flag) firstobs=3) have(drop=_all_ obs=2);
  lag1_flag=lag1(flag);
  lag2_flag=lag2(flag);
  if lag1_flag or lag2_flag or flag or lead1_flag or lead2_flag ;
run;
```

Results

```
                         lead1_    lead2_    lag1_    lag2_
Obs     code     flag     flag      flag      flag     flag

 1     abc123      0        0         1        .        .
 2     xyz456      0        1         0        0        .
 3     wer098      1        0         0        0        0
 4     jio234      0        0         0        1        0
 5     bcx190      0        0         0        0        1
 6     epj676      0        0         1        0        0
 7     ere654      0        1         0        0        0
 8     yru493      1        0         .        0        0
 9     ale674      0        .         .        1        0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data want(drop=_: i);
   merge have have(keep=flag firstobs=3 rename=(flag=_flag));
   if flag or _flag then i=1;
   if 0<i<=3 then do;
      output;
      i+1;
   end;
   else delete;
run;
```